# how to update particular json object inside json arry in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

```
{   
"userId" : "111",
"userName":"abc",
"skills":[
    {
        "DomainName" : "Application",
        "skillName" : "Python",
        "months" : "2",
        "level" : "8",
        "CertificationStatus" : "Yes"
    },
    {
        "DomainName" : "Application",
        "skillName" : "Angular",
        "months" : "0",
        "level" : "9",
        "CertificationStatus" : "Yes"
    },{
        "DomainName" : "Application",
        "skillName" : "Nodejs",
        "months" : "5",
        "level" : "6",
        "CertificationStatus" : "Yes"
    }

]
}
```

i want to update months: 3, level to 2 for nodejs..
if already existing it should update otherwise it should add that particular json inside array

commands i have used in flask using mongodb are:

```
skill ={
    "DomainName" : "Application",
    "skillName" : "Nodejs",
    "months" : "3",
    "level" : "2",
    "CertificationStatus" : "Yes"
      }
skills_dummy_collection = 
mongo.db.skills_master.find({'userId':'111'},{skills:{"$elematch": 
{'skills.skillName':'Nodejs'}}})

    if skills_dummy_collection:
      mongo.db.skills_master.update({"skills.skillName" 
      :'Nodejs','userId':'111'}, {"$set": {
      "skills":skill
      } })
      else:
      mongo.db.skills_master.insert(json_util._json_convert(skill))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way for you to do this in one single query.

What you could do is first to [**$addToSet**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) with an [**$elemMatch**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) which would take care of the cases where the record does not exists in the `skills` and then do a `$set` to take care of the cases where it does:

```
.update({
  userId: '111',
  'skills.skillName': { $not: { '$elemMatch' : { 'skillName' : 'Nodejs'}}}
}, {
  $addToSet: {
    "skills": {
      "DomainName": "Application",
      "skillName": "Nodejs",
      "months": "3",
      "level": "2",
      "CertificationStatus": "Yes"
    }
  }
})
```

The 2nd operation with the `$set` will update all records where `skills.months` is not equal to `"3"` and where `skillName` **is** `Nodejs`:

```
.update({
  userId: '111',
  'skills.skillName': 'Nodejs',
  'skills.months': { $ne: "3" }
}, {
  $set: {
    "skills.$": {
      "DomainName": "Application",
      "skillName": "Nodejs",
      "months": "3",
      "level": "2",
      "CertificationStatus": "Yes"
    }
  }
})
```

Note about `$addToSet`:

> he $addToSet operator adds a value to an array unless the value is
>   already present, in which case $addToSet does nothing to that array.